# finding next monday from a fixed date using momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

code:

```
var startDate = moment("10/3/2014");
var nf = moment(startDate).day("Monday")
alert(nf);
```

I am trying to find next monday from "10/3/2014", it should be "10/6/2014".

But the output is "Mon Sep 29 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530".

It is returning previous Monday.

My code may be completely wrong. what i am expecting is it should return me the next Monday date i.e "10/6/2014".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see code [here](http://jsbin.com/jidat/6/edit?html,output).Very simple

```
$('#next').text(moment(startDate).day(1+7));
```

Comment: MomentJS considers Sunday as the start of the week, so on Sunday's this will return Monday in 8 days time, not tomorrow which is 'next Monday' in common parlance ...